# AWS Glue write parquet with partitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I am able to write to parquet format and partitioned by a column like so:

```
jobname = args['JOB_NAME']
#header is a spark DataFrame
header.repartition(1).write.parquet('s3://bucket/aws-glue/{}/header/'.format(jobname), 'append', partitionBy='date')
```

But I am not able to do this with Glue's DynamicFrame.

```
header_tmp = DynamicFrame.fromDF(header, glueContext, "header")
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = header_tmp, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": 's3://bucket/output/header/'}, format = "parquet")
```

I have tried passing the `partitionBy` as a part of `connection_options` dict, since AWS docs say for parquet Glue does not support any format options, but that didn't work.

Is this possible, and how? As for reasons for doing it this way, I thought it was needed for job bookmarking to work, as that is not working for me currently.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From AWS Support (paraphrasing a bit):

As of today, Glue does not support partitionBy parameter when writing to parquet. This is in the pipeline to be worked on though.

Using the Glue API to write to parquet is *required* for job bookmarking feature to work with S3 sources.

So as of today it is not possible to partition parquet files *AND* enable the job bookmarking feature.

Edit: today (3/23/18) I found in the [documentations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-partitions.html):

```
glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
frame = projectedEvents,
connection_options = {"path": "$outpath", "partitionKeys": ["type"]},
format = "parquet")
```

That option may have always been there and both myself and the AWS support person missed it, or it was only added recently. Either way, it seems like it is possible now.

Comment: Here is the quote from the most recent glue documentation: "Until recently the only way to write a DynamicFrame into partitions was to convert it to a Spark SQL DataFrame before writing. However, DynamicFrames now support native partitioning using a sequence of keys, using the partitionKeys option when creating a sink.". So YES, it was added just recently

Comment: Still "partitionKeys": ["type"]  feature is useless ...you will get an empty folder if you specify a partitioning key in this option.

And if you remove this option then only your DF will get written in S3 with default no of partitions i.e. 200.

Comment: Does it write in append mode?

Comment: I used this newly added partitionKeys option and could write all data from the dynamic frame into SE folder in parquet format. The writing of data honoured the partitionKeys option as data is in folders created due to partitioning. However, when I try to run queries in Athena to retrieve same data, I found Athena always get empty dataset. Seems like the table created in Data catelog is not able to understand that the data in S3 is in partitioned format already. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

I use some of the columns from my dataframe as the partionkeys object:

```
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame \
    .from_options(
        frame = some_dynamic_dataframe, 
        connection_type = "s3", 
        connection_options =  {"path":"some_path", "partitionKeys": ["month", "day"]},
        format = "parquet")
```

Comment: Does it write in append mode?

Comment: For me this creates a file called `my_partition=my_partition_value_$folder$` in my output folder. So it doesn't have a file extension, but it's also not a folder and the size is 0B. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Omega also experiencing this issue - did you find any solution?